# Magento Advanced Search Page in Search Result Page

Tags: magento-1.9, search, advanced-search

How to show the Magento Advanced search page in "Search Result Page" if there is no search result for Magento simple search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with below.
Update your **app\design\frontend\YourPackage\YourTheme\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml**

```
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <?php if ($this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl() ?>" class="nobr link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
            <?php echo $message?><br />
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
<p class="note-msg">
    <?php echo ($this->getNoResultText()) ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Your search returns no results.') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
        <br /><?php echo $message?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalogsearch/advanced_form")->setTemplate("catalogsearch/advanced-form.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now create a new file **app\design\frontend\YourPackage\YourTheme\template\catalogsearch\advanced-form.phtml**

```
<?php $maxQueryLength= $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getMaxQueryLength();?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("catalogsearch/advanced/result/") ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset advanced-search">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Try Advance Search') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list" id="advanced-search-list">
            <?php foreach ($this->getSearchableAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
            <?php $_code = $_attribute->getAttributeCode() ?>
            <li>
                <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute) ?></label>
                <?php switch($this->getAttributeInputType($_attribute)):
                    case 'number': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="<?php echo $_code ?>[from]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'from')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>" class="input-text validate-number" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="<?php echo $_code ?>[to]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'to')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_to" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>" class="input-text validate-number" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'price': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <input name="<?php echo $_code ?>[from]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'from')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text validate-number" type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <input name="<?php echo $_code ?>[to]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute, 'to')) ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>_to" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text validate-number" type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                        <small>(<?php echo $this->getCurrency($_attribute); ?>)</small>
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'select': ?>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getAttributeSelectElement($_attribute) ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'yesno': ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAttributeYesNoElement($_attribute) ?>
                    <?php break;
                    case 'date': ?>
                    <div class="input-range">
                        <?php echo $this->getDateInput($_attribute, 'from') ?>
                        <span class="separator">-</span>
                        <?php echo $this->getDateInput($_attribute, 'to') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php break;
                    default: ?>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $_code ?>" id="<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeValue($_attribute)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAttributeLabel($_attribute)) ?>"  class="input-text <?php echo $this->getAttributeValidationClass($_attribute) ?>" maxlength="<?php echo $maxQueryLength;?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php endswitch; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('advanced-search-list')</script>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php

and replace this

```
 $query->prepare();
```

with below line

```
 return $this->_redirect('catalogsearch/advanced');
```